# Not to password protect a php in Apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, centos7

I have Apache httpd installed on my CentOS 7. By adding the following code in httpd.conf, I can password protect my website

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /var/www/password/htpasswd
  Require user validUser

  <Files index.php>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Since I want to have /var/www/html/index.php not password protected, `Require all granted` is added as shown. This, however, still requires me username and password. Please help, thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't protect the complete directory but protect using a LocationMatch:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!index\.php).|index\.php.+$">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /var/www/password/htpasswd
  Require user validUser
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks answering, but sorry that it doesn't work. Since there are some more private pages under /var/www/html, I would like to only allow accessing index.php without authentication. That's why I protected the whole directory.

Comment: Yes, I did get that. The LocationMatch protects everything but /index.php.

Comment: Thanks friend. I finally find out what's wrong. I'm now using wordpress and all the sub-folders are protected. When I access index.php, those protected contents are accessed, so it looks like that index.php is also password protected.